# how can I select all li elements with a span of text value equal to a number using xpath not absolute?

Tags: python, html, xpath

the link is: https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=burger&find_loc=Louisville%2C+KY&ns=1
and if you right click and inspect the '1' besides Six fork's burger, the xpath is
/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/h4/span
with span text has value of a number,

I want to create an xpath which selects all 'li' tag with 'span' that has numbers value of text, that is child of 'li'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an xpath expression like

```
//ul/li[@class="lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]//h4/span/text()[1]
```

and see if it works.